# How do I save all generated Lines on the screen

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, line, renderer

I have two moving Objects and want to connect them with multiple lines. The Lines will be drawn, but disappearing when a new one is created.

How can I save all generated lines ?

```
void CreateLine()
{
    line = new GameObject("Line" + currLines).AddComponent<LineRenderer>();
    line = GetComponent<LineRenderer>();
    line.SetPosition(0, Pos1);
    line.SetPosition(1, Pos2);
    line.startColor = Color.white;
    line.endColor = Color.white;
    line.startWidth = 5;
    line.endWidth = 5;
    line.positionCount = 2;
    line.sortingOrder = 2;
    line.useWorldSpace = true;
    currLines++;
}

void Start()
{
    Pos1 = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Pos1");
    Pos2 = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Pos2");

    InvokeRepeating("CreateLine", 0, 0.05f);
}
```

Comment: "line" variable will be overwritten each time you call CreateLine, what about make It local, not global?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code:

```
public class LinesCreator : MonoBehaviour
{
   LineRenderer line;
   GameObject Pos1, Pos2;
   int currLines=0;

   Vector3 pos1, pos2;

   void CreateLine()
   {
       // To avoid creating multiple lines in the same positions.
       if (Pos1.transform.position == pos1 && Pos2.transform.position == pos2)
        return;

    line = new GameObject("Line" + currLines).AddComponent<LineRenderer>();
    //line = GetComponent<LineRenderer>(); // This will return the GameObject's line renerer, not the new GameObject's line rendere

       pos1 = Pos1.transform.position;
       pos2 = Pos2.transform.position;
       line.SetPosition(0, pos1);
       line.SetPosition(1, pos2);
       line.startColor = Color.white;
       line.endColor = Color.white;
       line.startWidth = 0.7f;
       line.endWidth = 0.7f;
       line.positionCount = 2;
       line.sortingOrder = 2;
       line.useWorldSpace = true;
       currLines++;
   }

   void Start()
   {
       Pos1 = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Pos1");
       Pos2 = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Pos2");

       InvokeRepeating("CreateLine", 0, 0.05f);
   }
}
```

The changes I made:

First of all, for the program to work as you want is to, remove *line = GetComponent();* (I commented it out).

What this line does is to set *line* to the gameObject's lineRenderer (the gameObject who has the script on it).

We don't want that because we want the line to be on the new gameObject.

Second, I add a condition that helps you not to create line you don't need.

I did this by compering the last position and the current positions, if both of them (the objects) didn't move - you don't need do draw a new line.